# Show that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-x} \rightarrow 1$ converges uniformly.

Tags: uniform-convergence

This is my attempt at a proof:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=\lim_{m \to 0}\frac{log(1+mx)}{m}=\lim_{m \to 0} \frac{x}{1+mx}=x \iff (1+\frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow e^x$ uniformly.

It follows that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-x} \rightarrow 1$ uniformly.

Is this sufficient?

Comment: That's just pointwise convergence..

Comment: That sequence of functions has a wild behaviour on $\mathbb{R}^-$. Moreover, $f_n(n)$ is exponentially small, how can ve have uniform convergence towards $1$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's what my real analysis professor wanted us to show. Somehow I can't do more than show point-wise convergence.

Comment: @AidanRocke: maybe the real question was to prove uniform convergence towards $1$ on $[0,1]$, not on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why $[0,1]$ and not $[-\alpha,\alpha] \exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ But no, that's not what he asked explicitly.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Maybe we were meant to conclude that it doesn't converge uniformly.

Comment: Perhaps the question was "uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\Bbb R$"?  It is quite common for functions to converge uniformly on compact sets, but not on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have no clue why my question got down-voted. That's harsh. I repeat, this is exactly the question he asked.

Comment: @AidanRocke I have no idea why it was downvoted either. I didn't do it. I simply offered a possibility on what when wrong here. I just upvoted the question just because I find these "drive-by downvoters" annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = \left(1+\frac xn \right)^n e^{-x}$. In order for $f_n$ to converge to $f\equiv 1$ uniformly, we must have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-1|=0. $$ Since $f_n\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathbb R$ is not bounded, any minimum or maximum value must be obtained as a critical point, i.e. a point $x$ such that $f_n'(x)=0$. Computing the derivative:
$$
f_n'(x) = -\frac xn\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n-1}e^{-x},
$$
it follows that $f_n'(x)=0$ implies $x=0$ or $x=-n$. As $f_n(-n)=0$, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} |f_n(x)-1| \geqslant 1, $$
and hence $f_n$ does not converge uniformly.

Edit: if $f_n$ is defined on $[0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb R$, then $n\notin[0,1]$ for $n>1$, so a minimum/maximum value must be obtained on the boundary of $[0,1]$. We compute $f_n(0) = 1$ and
$$f_n(1) = \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n e^{-1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 1, $$
so indeed $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Edit: if $f_n$ is defined on a compact set $K\subset\mathbb R$, then $K\subset[-M,M]$ for some $M>0$. Then choosing $n>M$, we see that again an extreme value of $f_n$ must be obtained at $x=M$ or $x=-M$. Since
$$f_n(-M) = \left(1 - \frac Mn\right)^n e^M\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 1$$
and
$$f_n(M) = \left(1 + \frac Mn\right)^n e^{-M}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 1,$$
we see again that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $1$.

Comment: Pedantic point: it could also be $-n$. But the situation is similar there. Also, it doesn't even really have to be $[0,1]$, it will work on any compact set. (This situation is common: even "nice" convergent sequences of functions on unbounded domains rarely converge uniformly on the whole space. But they often converge uniformly on compact subsets.)

Comment: @Ian Fair enough, I added that case. But $f_n(-n)=0$ for all $n$ so it is a rather moot point (although I suppose taking that sequence would simplify the argument).

Comment: Full pedantry included in the answer :)

Comment: Isn't $f'(x) = -\frac{x}{n} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1} e^{-x}$?

Comment: @Keba Indeed, I've corrected the error.