# Show that $f_n=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ converge uniformly on all compact of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$. Show that it converges uniformly to $e^x$ on every compact $K\subset \mathbb R$.

This is how I would like to do:

Let $K$ a compact. Let $g_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-e^x$. Since $g_n$ is continuous on $K$, it take it's maximum on $K$. Let denote $a_n\in K$ s.t. $|g_n(x)|\leq g_n(a_n)$ for all $n$. Set $b_n=g_n(a_n)$. How can I show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty }b_n=0\ \ ?$$

I tried to show by induction that $(b_n)$ is decreasing, but it looks very complicate. And even if it converge, it looks complicate to show that it converge to $0$ as well.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462404/show-that-1-fracxnn-e-x-rightarrow-1-converges-uniformly
See the last part of the accepted answer.

Comment: You can use Dini's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem). Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and show that $f_n(x)$ is monotonic in $n$ on $[-N,N]$ for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimating the maximum of $g$ seems difficult. Here's a different approach.

Let $M>0$ and $x\in [-M,M]$.

The following holds:

$$|e^x-f_n(x)|=
\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}\right|=
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\left( 1-\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!} \right)\right|$$

Now, notice that $$\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!} = \frac{(n-k+1)\ldots n}{n\cdot n\ldots n}\leq 1$$

Applying triangular inequality and noting that $|x|\leq M$ yields
$$|e^x-f_n(x)|\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{M^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{M^k}{k!}\left( 1-\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!} \right)$$

But the last quantity is the exact expansion of $e^M-f_n(M)$

Hence $\forall M>0, \forall x\in [-M,M], |e^x-f_n(x)|\leq e^M-f_n(M)$

Hence uniform convergence.

Note that this proof readily adapts to show that $f_n=(1+\frac{z}{n})^n$ converges uniformly on all compact subset  of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Just a small remark: you forgot to use $n!/[n^k (n-k)!]\leq 1$ in the next inequality.

Comment: What kind of the triangular inequality did you use?