# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n}} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{k}(k+3)}$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n}} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{k}(k+3)}.$$

**My work**:  I tried using sum of binomial coefficients. I could not find a general term to find the limit.

Comment: What exactly is the denominator?

Comment: i hope its clear now

Comment: (k+3) is in the denominator?

Comment: Option 1) or 2)? 1) $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n}} \binom{n}{k}\frac{k+3}{n^{k}}$
2) $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n}} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{k}(k+3)}$

Comment: i mean option 2

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Notice that, by the binomial theorem,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{k}(k+3)}&=
\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\int_{0}^1x^{k+2}dx
\\&=
\int_{0}^1x^2\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^kdx\\
&=\int_{0}^1x^2\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\,dx.
\end{align}$$
Then use [Show that $f_n=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ converge uniformly on all compact of $\mathbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661442/show-that-f-n-1-fracxnn-converge-uniformly-on-all-compact-of-mathbb)?