# Uniformly convergent on each compact set of $\mathbb R$ but not on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

As the title says, I am looking for a sequence of function which is uniformly convergent on all compact sets of $\mathbb R$ but not on $\mathbb R$.

I thought $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ is such a function since for any x in a bounded and closed subset of $\mathbb R$. $\sup(f_n(x)-f(x)) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. But since $\mathbb R$ is unbounded $x$ can get infinitely large thus the function sequence does not uniformly converge on $\mathbb{R}$. I wanted to check if my understanding is correct. Thank you

Comment: Yes - good example.

Comment: Check my edits to improve your MathJax skills.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2760622/148510) is another example of what you are looking for where it is a little more difficult to prove uniform convergence on the compact intervals.

Comment: @RRL thanks a lot

Comment: Another, more difficult example, is $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^nx^j/j!$ with $f(x)=e^x.$  A theorem in analysis is that if a power series in $x$ converges  at every $x$ then the convergence is uniform on any compact set. But $f_n$ is a polynomial and $e^x-p(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ for any polynomial $p.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained above in the post, the answer is {$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}; n \geq 1$ and $x \in \mathbb R $}